# nodejs custom error response does not take code error argument

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm workin with a custom error response that I found in a tutorial. it's working correctly in all the node server, but in a specifies line it doesn't take the argument that specified the error code. It should return a 401 error but instead is returning me a 500 error code.

**errorResponse.js**

```
class ErrorResponse extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}


module.exports = ErrorResponse;
```

The next is the porcion of code that doesn't working well.

**auth.js**

```
return next(new ErrorResponse('Unauthorized', 401))
```

If I use this aproach the error code is the correct.

```
return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized')
```

*Edited and share server.js*

```
require('dotenv').config({path: './config.env'});
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const errorHandler = require('./middlewares/error');

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/private', require('./routes/private'));



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server on port', PORT));

process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
    console.log(`logged Error: ${err}`)
    server.close(() => process.exit(1))
});

app.use(errorHandler);
```

***error.js***

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) =>{
    let error = { ...err };

    error.message = err.message

    if(err.code === 11000) {
        const message = `Error de duplicación`;
        error = new ErrorResponse(message, 400)
    }

    if(err.name === "ValidationError") {
        const message = Object.values(err.errors).map((val) => val.message);
        err = new ErrorResponse(message, 400)
    }
    res.status(error.status || 500 ).json({
        succes: false,
        error: error.message || "Error del servidor"
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you add error handler in the server file at the bottom to catch all errors? Can you share it (server.js)?

Comment: I have just done it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now we need the `errorHandler` function to see how the errors are handled

Comment: @BlackMath the section is pasted

Comment: I have just find my mistake, was in the error handler. My bad.

Comment: What was your error?